# Android Wear Launch Cards

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to make an Android Wear app which essentially interfaces with preexisting Google Cards. Is there a way to easily launch the preexisting weather card? The card that's brought up when one speaks "weather" into Google Now on the Moto?

In short, I want to launch the stock weather notification provided by Google programatically in my own Android Wear app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The stock cards are not designed to be interacted within that way. I would recommend learning more about android wear notifications and making your own weather card.

This option will additionally create a much more consistent experience in your app, rather than repurposing something that already has a set context in which it is intended to appear.

Also, context cards such as the weather card are never part of an app, but rather part of the context stream. To launch your own cards in the context stream you must use the NotificationManager.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html